# why does my contract say honeypot?

Tags: solidity, remix, bscscan

https://bscscan.com/address/0x4451f5016724867fd00438eb30d5b2f23d3d69bd

This is my code source. TokenSniffer does not pick it up and staysafu says its a honeypot, the token is tradeable

Comment: i removed liq. after removing liq, staysafu then read it as not a honeypot. Im so confused

Comment: its seems to read not a honey pot after removing liq. something is reading the opposite of what is there

Comment: Hi Thomas! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! You should contact staysafu and ask for a review, perhaps it is an automated false positive.